# Full Calendar Not Showing Events Coming From Firebase Firestore in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, fullcalendar

I am using the package `@fullcalendar/react` to create a calendar in my admin dashboard website. What I want is to allow admins to add events and they would show up in the full calendar from the firebase firestore database.

But when I fetch my events collection it just displays nothing in the calendar.

What am I doing wrong? Why are the events not showing up?

Here is the console log of my eventsData Array.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
import FullCalendar from "@fullcalendar/react";
import dayGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/daygrid";
import interactionPlugin, { Draggable } from "@fullcalendar/interaction";
import BootstrapTheme from "@fullcalendar/bootstrap";
import firebase from '../../firebase';

const Calender = props => {

 const [eventsData, setEventsData] = useState({})

 const getEventsData = async () => { 
    await firebase.firestore().collection("Events").get().then((snapshot) => {
      const events = snapshot.docs.map(event => event.data());
      setEventsData(events)
      console.log(events)
    }).catch((e) => {
      console.log(e + "fetching error")
    })
  }

 useEffect(() => {
    getEventsData()
  },[])


       return(

                   <FullCalendar
                        plugins={[
                          BootstrapTheme,
                          dayGridPlugin,
                          interactionPlugin,
                        ]}
                        slotDuration={"00:15:00"}
                        handleWindowResize={true}
                        themeSystem="bootstrap"
                        headerToolbar={{
                          left: "prev,next today",
                          center: "title",
                          right: "dayGridMonth,dayGridWeek,dayGridDay",
                        }}
                        events={eventsData}
                        editable={true}
                        droppable={true}
                        selectable={true}
                   
                      />

              )
            }
```

Comment: Please provide all data as text, not pictures. A JSON representation of the data would be best. Thanks

Comment: Anyway since the request is asynchronous it probably tries to pass the event data to fullcalendar before it's been populated from firebase. Prefer implementing a dynamic event feed in fullcalendar using the callback function pattern shown in the fullcalendar documentation

Comment: @ADyson you were right, the async/await was the problem. Many thanks!

Comment: @OsamaJamal Good job on finding the solution to your own question. As soon as you are able to, try posting your answer as a formal answer to help other users that have a similar problem

Comment: @OsamaJamal Can you please post the answer to this question? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with my code was that I was using and async function to get my data and that was not making the data to be shown. removing the async/await fixed the issue.

```
const getEventsData = () => { 
    firebase.firestore().collection("Events").get().then((snapshot) => {
      const events = snapshot.docs.map(event => event.data());
      setEventsData(events)
      console.log(events)
    }).catch((e) => {
      console.log(e + "fetching error")
    })
  }
```