# Fullcalendar events from firebase not displaying

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, fullcalendar

I am trying to display events in a Fullcalendar component in react. I am not getting any errors, however no events are displaying. When I log what is being stored in my state variable (used to store the data), I see:

```
events
: 
{id: '1', title: 'test', start: '2022-10-21T13:13:55.008'}
id
: 
"EaINbYH4reC03zyxuuYm"
```

This is how the Fullcalendar documentation (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/events-array) says an event should be structed as an array:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  events: [
    {
      title  : 'event1',
      start  : '2010-01-01'
    },
    {
      title  : 'event2',
      start  : '2010-01-05',
      end    : '2010-01-07'
    },
    {
      title  : 'event3',
      start  : '2010-01-09T12:30:00',
      allDay : false // will make the time show
    }
  ]
});
```

My code here below (I first query a user database table to get all the id's of the sessions to which they belong, and then I use those IDs to query a database table containing more details of the sessions)

```
import React, { createRef, useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/react' // must go before plugins
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid' // a plugin!
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid';
import '../styles/Styles.css';
import { users, allSessions } from '../lib/firestore-collections';
import { query, where, getDocs, collection} from "firebase/firestore";
import { useAuth } from '../contexts/auth-context';
import { Navigate, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import {motion} from 'framer-motion';


async function getSessionIDs(userId) { // <-- note switching to argument here
  const qUserSessions = collection(users, userId, "sessions");
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(qUserSessions);
  return querySnapshot.docs
    .map(({ id }) => ({ id })); // this shorthand only works for extracting IDs
}

async function getSessionsData(userId) {
  const sessionIDArray = await getSessionIDs(userId);

  console.log(sessionIDArray);
  if (sessionIDArray.length === 0) // this is known as the fail-fast/guard pattern
    return []; // no sessions atm

    let sessionIDs = [];

    sessionIDArray.forEach(element => {
      sessionIDs.push(element.id);
    })


  // if here, we've got sessions to fetch

  // WARNING: The 'in' operator can only handle up to 10 sessions at a time!
  const qSessionData = query(allSessions, where('__name__', "in", sessionIDs));
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(qSessionData);
  return querySnapshot.docs
    .map((doc) => ({
      events: doc.data(),
      id: doc.id
    })); // note removal of error suppression
}


export default function Calendar() {

    const calendarRef = createRef()

    const { currentUser } = useAuth();
    const [sessions, setSessions] = useState([]);
    const [error, setError] = useState([]);
  
    const userId = currentUser && currentUser.uid;
  
  
    useEffect(() => {
  
      if (!userId) {
        setSessions([]); // no user logged in, do nothing
      }
  
      // for tracking if component was detached
      let detached = false;
  
  
      getSessionsData(userId)
        .then((sessionsData) => {
          if (detached) return; // detached? do nothing
  
          if (sessionsData.length === 0){
            setError("No sessions found.");
          }
          setSessions(sessionsData);
          console.log(sessionsData);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          if (detached) return; // detached? ignore error
          console.error('Failed to get user session data:', err);
        });
  
      return () => detached = true;
    }, [userId]); // rerun when user changes
  
    if (!userId){
      Navigate('/login');
      return;
    }

let htmlCode;

    if (sessions.length !== 0){
      htmlCode = ( <div className="calendarStyles">
    {sessions.map((session) => (
   <h1>{session.events.title}</h1>
 ))}
<FullCalendar
ref={calendarRef}
 plugins={[ dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin ]}
 initialView="dayGridMonth" // dummy events
 events = {sessions.events}
 progressiveEventRendering = 'true'
 customButtons={{
   myTimeDayBut: {
     text: "timeDay",
     click() {

       const calendar = calendarRef.current; 

       if (calendar){
         const calendarApi = calendar.getApi();
         
         calendarApi.changeView("timeGridDay");
       }
     },
   },
   myTimeWeekBut: {
     text: "timeWeek",
     click() {

       const calendar = calendarRef.current; 

       if (calendar){
         const calendarApi = calendar.getApi();
         
         calendarApi.changeView("timeGridWeek");
       }
     },
   },
 }}
 headerToolbar={{
   left: "prev,next",
   center: "title",
   right: "today,myTimeDayBut,myTimeWeekBut,dayGridMonth",
 }}
/>
</div>);
    }
    else{
      htmlCode = (<></>);
    }

    return (
    <>
    {htmlCode}
    </>
    )
  }
```

Comment: Have a look at this stackoveflow [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/72856170/18265638)

Comment: N.B. Why are you looking at the v3 documentation when clearly you're not using that version? But anyway, the event array structure hasn't changed that much, thankfully